# Jupyter notebook "Click to add a cell." breaks commandmode

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I freshly installed Jupyter on a Linuxsystem via the packagemanager and whenever I have selected the last cell in command mode and press J the option to "Click to add cell." appears.

Once it appears the only Keys still working are Enter, adding a new Cell but leaving the "Click to add cell." Button marked, or pressing Shift+Enter executing the last cell, adding a new one and putting me into insert mode in the now new cell.

I Reinstalled and tried every Escape + possible function key

Comment: Which version of Jupyter are you using?

Comment: GitHub issues here: https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/7118, https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/15224

Answer (score 0):

This has been [fixed](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/pull/14796) in **Jupyter Notebook v7.0.6** and **JupyterLab v4.0.7**, respectively.

You can't disable the "Click to add cell" button, however, it doesn't break command mode anymore, i.e. when it's focused, you can just type `K` to navigate back to the last cell.